# Make Directory Permission denied, but permissions are set correctly

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, centos7

I am trying to create a simple php script that creates a directory in /var/www/html. The code is:

```
$dir = '/var/www/html/testdir';

 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
     $oldmask = umask(0);  // helpful when used in linux server
mkdir($dir, 0777, true) || chmod($dir, 0777);
     mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }
```

The problem is, I get a permission error when this is executed. But the permissions for the html directory is:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 7 apache apache 4096 Jun 18 11:46 html
```

Here is the error:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/createdir.php on line 6
```

Also, `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` tells me php is running as apache.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. Linux was blocking Apache from creating directories.

Fix:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /path/to/www/dir/for/rw
```